# How to add a UIView to an UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uialertview

I have to create a custom `AlertView` with a view that contain some label. I create the .h and .m of `CustomAlert`

this is the `CustomAlert.h`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomAlert: UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ok;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ok1;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ok2;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ok3;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ok4;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *ok5;


@end
```

and this is the `CustomAlert.m`.

```
#import "CustomAlert.h"

@implementation CustomAlert

@synthesize ok = _ok;
@synthesize ok1 = _ok1;
@synthesize ok2 = _ok2;
@synthesize ok3 = _ok3;
@synthesize ok4 = _ok4;
@synthesize ok5 = _ok5;;

@end
```

I also create the xib with just a view and i connect the label with all the "ok".

Now, i want to add this View to an AlertView with just an Ok button. How can i do it? I want to use it with ios 7 and 6.

Thanks!!

Comment: Now, i want to add this View to an AlertView with just an Ok button - What?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha i want to create an UIAlertView with inside the CustomAlert.

Comment: you want to add an UIAlertView as a subviw to the CustomAleet? I'm afraid you cannot do that.

Comment: Try https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview this may help you

Comment: @AndreyChernukha but if i use this:  
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
            [av setValue:v forKey:@"accessoryView"];
            v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            [av show];
I added a simple yellow view to the alert..so I would like to add a view with what I need to the alert.

Comment: There used to be a supported way to do this in < iOS6 but it has been removed in iOS7. In the developer forums Apple have been pretty explicit about not doing this. You are better to build your own modal alerts or, as suggested above, look for a prebuilt alternative. The fact that you can force a subview into a UIAlertView does not mean you should do it.

Comment: You can look up a list of various customizable UIAlertView alternatives here: http://maniacdev.com/2013/10/highly-customizable-ios-7-style-uialertview-replacement-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 7 you should not munge a UIAlertView like this - and there is no need, because thanks to custom view transitions you can make your own small presented view in front of your interface, so that it looks and acts like a UIAlertView but can contain anything you like.

I've written an online tutorial on how to do this:

http://programming.oreilly.com/2014/01/transcending-uialertview-on-ios-7.html

And there's a downloadable github project that goes with it:

https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7